# Alternating series question

Tags: limits, summation

So I have two sums and the question is whether they converge or diverge.

$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-3)^n}{2^n+3^n} =\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2/3)^n+1} $ Now $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{(2/3)^n+1}}=1\neq0$ The alternating series test states that if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{a_n}=0$ and $a_n$ is decreasing then the sum is convergent. So does it mean if it is not zero then it is diverging? Can I conclude that my sum diverging ?

And the second one:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{2001}(-1)^n.$ So $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{n^{2001}}=\infty $. Can I conclude something from there?

Comment: A necessary condition for $\;\sum a_n\;$ to converge is that $\;a_n\longrightarrow 0\;$ . You've found both your series fail this condition so those series don't converge.

Comment: Sorry I editted first sum's limit. I know that condition but in alternating series you consider the limit of $ a_n$ where $ (-1)^n $ is not a part of it. I.e. $\sum{(-1)^na_n} $ 
If I just look at $a_n $ as $\frac{(-1)^n}{(2/3)^n+1}$ then I don't know what is its limit. I assume it does not have one.

Comment: The limit of the absolute value is $\;\frac1{0+1}=1\neq 0\;$ ...

Comment: Yeah of course...Makes sense now. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first sum, it is not so much divergent as it is undefined.  As you approach infinity, the sum's terms will be $\{\ldots,1,-1,1,-1\ldots\}$ and so will rotate between two points.  Since the absolute value of $a_n$ is finite and constant, it cannot converge or diverge.  As an example, you might want to consider $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n $$  This only alternates between $0$ and $1$.

For the other sum, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nn^{2001}$ does have the property of being divergent.  One way to tell is to take $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left((2n)^{2001}-(2n-1)^{2001}\right)$.  This is a strictly positive sequence with terms rapidly *increasing*.  Clearly, this is divergent.